# How to create a stage in API Gateway with enabled cloudwatch metrics using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform

I want to deploy this in a stage with cloudwatch metrics enabled. For that i need to use `aws_api_gateway_method_settings` which needs stage name. If don't create a stage using `aws_api_gateway_stage` it is throwing an error saying stage not exists. When i am trying to create a stage its saying stage already exists.

One solution i tried is creating two stages one using `aws_api_gateway_deployment` and another using `aws_api_gateway_stage` with two different names. Is there any other solution for this?

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "test-deploy" {
  depends_on = [ /*something goes here*/]

  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test.id}"
  stage_name  = "${var.stage_name}"

  variables = {
    "function" = "${var.lambda_function_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "test" {
  stage_name = "${var.stage_name}"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test.id}"
  deployment_id = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.test-deploy.id}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "settings" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test.id}"
  stage_name  = "${aws_api_gateway_stage.test.stage_name}"
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level = "INFO"
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
aws_api_gateway_stage.test: Error creating API Gateway Stage: ConflictException: Stage already exists
```

Comment: Seems you have that stag created already, clean it from console first.

Comment: @BMW, I am not creating anything from console.  `aws_api_gateway_deployment` and `aws_api_gateway_stage` trying to create stage seperately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that we don't need to create a stage explicitly. `aws_api_gateway_deployment` creates a stage, but need to set `depends_on`. I tried this earlier without `depends_on` which throws an error saying `stage not exists`.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "test-deploy" {
  depends_on = [ /*something goes here*/]
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test.id}"
  stage_name  = "${var.stage_name}"
  variables = {
    "function" = "${var.lambda_function_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "settings" {
  depends_on  = ["aws_api_gateway_deployment.test-deploy"]
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test.id}"
  stage_name  = "${var.stage_name}"
  method_path = "*/*"
  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level = "INFO"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using access logs by any chance? I'm having trouble working out how to use those... given you have to define a stage to use them, and doing so conflicts with the stage defined by the deployment, as you found!

Comment: Hi @TimMalone did you figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: @Jonathan I think I did. I think I ended up leaving the stage_name in the deployment blank - see https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2918#issuecomment-356684239

Answer (score 0):

You can enable API gateway access log in Terraform using the following code:

```
locals {
  operations = <<TXT
  '[ { "op" : "replace", "path" : "/accessLogSettings/destinationArn", "value" : "aws_cloudwatch_log_group_arn"},
  { "op" : "replace", "path" : "/accessLogSettings/format", "value" : log_format}]'
  TXT
}

resource "null_resource" "access_log" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =<<CMD
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id api_gw_id --stage-name stage_name --patch-operations ${local.operations}
CMD
  }
}
```